# How to reset tab (or tab controller) of UITabBarController when user select tab?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Swift: I have UITabBarController, with 8 tabs. When user select any tab including more tab, I want reset content of selected tab by Popping to rootView controller?

How could this be done?

I tried to reset navigation controllers in below methods, It works for tabs which are visible at bottom but it doesn't work for `More` tab.

```
tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) 

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A clean way to do this:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    let index = tabBarController.selectedIndex
    if index == NSNotFound || index > 4 {
        tabBarController.moreNavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
        return
    }
    let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers?[tabBarController.selectedIndex] as? UINavigationController
    navController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
}
```

Create a custom class for your UITabViewContoller, set a delegate and put there that piece of code.

Comment: kamil3 It works for tabs which are visible at bottom, but doesn't work for More Tab :(

Comment: @GauravBorole Generally Apple dissuades using more than 5 tabs in tab bar: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/tab-bars/. Of course that doesn't change the fact that you're right.

Comment: kamil3 Yes Thats true, But thats the situation :)

Comment: @GauravBorole I edited my answer - it turns out UITabBarController has _moreNavigationController_ property. Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: kamil3 Thanks It works for more tab as well. But I think for MoreTab we need to add check if it is MoreTab index then Pop to root view.

Comment: @GauravBorole I added a statement checking if it's _MoreTab_. Also, I changed a delegate method, because it indicated on wrong _selectedIndex_ and it sometimes crashed. It was caused by _MoreTab_ that returns `NSNotFound` value in _selectedIndex_. Check if it's all OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142916/discussion-between-kamil3-and-gaurav-borole).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UITabBarController class for your tabBar and in that class ovveride the tabBar didSelect method from their on select of any tab you can popViewController

```
 class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
        override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
            let navigationController1 =  self.viewControllers![0] as? UINavigationController
            navigationController1!.popViewController(animated: false)

            let navigationController2 =  self.viewControllers![1] as? UINavigationController
            navigationController2!.popToRootViewController(animated: false)


            let navigationController3 =  self.viewControllers![2] as? UINavigationController
            navigationController3!.popToRootViewController(animated: false)

            let navigationController4 =  self.viewControllers![3] as? UINavigationController
            navigationController4!.popToRootViewController(animated: false)

        }
}
```

Comment: It works for tabs which are visible at bottom, but doesn't work for More Tab :(

Comment: add a screenshot of your storyboard in the question

Comment: ViewControllers are programmatically added to UITabBarController. But I guess it doesn't matter wether you are using Storyboard and Programatic way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `viewControllers` property of `UITabbarController`. viewControlers is an array of UIViewController for UITabbarController. Exchange/Move position of view controllers upon tabbar(controller) selection.

Use tabbar(controller)'s delegate method to hanlde these operations, like:

**Swift 3**

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    if var viewcontrollers = tabBarController.viewControllers {
        viewcontrollers.remove(at: tabBarController.selectedIndex)
        viewcontrollers.insert(viewController, at: 0)
        tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers
    }
}
```

You can also use this delegate method, if you have an access to tabbarController where you have implemented.

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
 // Write a similar code to exchange/move view controllers using tabbarController instance.       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    guard let navigationController = tabBarController.viewControllers?[tabBarController.selectedIndex] as? UINavigationController else {
        return
    }

    navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Did you put this in your UITabBarController class? (I tried this in a custom UITabBarController class assigned to a TabBar Interface Builder item).

Answer (score 0):

To fully support `More`, create a custom class like below:

```
class Main_TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.customizableViewControllers = []  //remove Edit from More (OPTIONAL)
    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        if let index = tabBar.items?.firstIndex(of: item) {
            if let count = viewControllers?.count, count > 5, index == 4 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.moreNavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
                }
            } else if let vcs = viewControllers, let vc = vcs[index] as? UINavigationController {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    vc.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```